# How to load multiple files in using YAML in perl

Tags: perl, yaml

i need to load two different config files in perl using YAML,

> use YAML qw'LoadFile';

then in first function i used

> my $conf = LoadFile('/config/test.yaml'); my $serve = $conf->{test};

and in 2nd one i used

> my $conf = LoadFile( '/config/XYZ.yaml');  my $key = $conf->{xyz};

now the in this case if i used only one file then its works fine, but used them simultaneously gives me error.
Do anyone know its reason?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @MattJacob actually the code doesn't work after this statement

Comment: "The code doesn't work"? What exactly does that mean?

Comment: i mean, i used this statement "printf("requested $serve\n");" to display its value , but it doesn't execute and stop working

Comment: @MattJacob can u provide me an example or appropriate link in which two files are loaded using YAML in perl,

Comment: We can't help you solve the problem without a clear description of what you expect to happen when you run your code and what actually does happen. "It doesn't work", "it doesn't execute", and "stop working" tell us essentially nothing about what _does_ happen. Do you get an error message? Does your computer lock up? Do flames shoot out of the keyboard and then the monitor sprouts wings and flies away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you haven't given anywhere near enough information for us to diagnose your problem, but here's a demonstration of loading two different YAML files, as you asked. As you can see, it's pretty much identical to what you have shown of your own code, which should work fine

#### test.yaml

```yaml
---
test: value for test
```

#### XYZ.yaml

```yaml
---
xyz: value for xyz
```

#### test.pl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use YAML qw/ LoadFile /;

my $conf = LoadFile('test.yaml');
say $conf->{test};

$conf = LoadFile('XYZ.yaml');
say $conf->{xyz};
```

#### output

```
value for test
value for xyz
```

Comment: @Luna: If you still need help, then you should open another question with more information about your Perl code and your data

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in your question, you talked about loading the two files in different functions. So I altered [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34041051/7231) to better reflect what I think you are doing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use YAML qw/ LoadFile /;

sub load_test {
  my $conf = LoadFile('test.yaml');
  my $test = $conf->{test};
  say $test;
}

sub load_xyz {
  my $conf = LoadFile('XYZ.yaml');
  my $xyz = $conf->{xyz};
  say $xyz;
}

load_test();
load_xyz();
```

When I run that, I get:

```
value for test
value for xyz
```

So I can't see what the problem is. If you want more help then you are going to need to give us a lot more detail.